# How set duration of the ringtone's play

Tags: java, android, ringtone

My app play ringtone. My code:

```
RingtoneManager.getRingtone( context, RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri( RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)).play();
```

Ringtone play very well. But if ringtone is long I need cut the first N milliseconds from it.

1. How get full duration of this ringtone?
2. How set maximum duration in milliseconds of this ringtone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the RingTone in mediaPlayer
for eg

```
Mediaplayer mp =new MediaPlayer();
uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri( RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
mp.setDataSoure(getApplicationContext(), uri);
mp.prepare();
mp.getDuration()
```

Use the mp.getDuration and do whatever u want.
Enjoy

Comment: @TapaSave Glad to help you. Enjoy coding.Happy Coding